# With "per partes" (by parts) derive a recurrent formula for the calculation of the integral

Tags: integration

With "per partes" (by parts) derive a recurrent formula for the calculation of the integral

$$I_n(x)= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^2)^{\large{n}}} \quad ,\quad  n \in \Bbb N$$

Please, help with this problem.

Comment: Note that your integral is not a function of $x$, so the left side should just be $I_n$.  The $x$ on the right is a dummy variable.

Answer (score 3):

if my assumption about your question is correct, then we should write:
$$
I_n=\int \frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^n}
$$
so
$$
I_n= \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n} - \int x \frac{d}{dx}\frac1{(1+x^2)^n} dx 
$$
$$
= \frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n} + 2n \int \frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^{n+1}} dx$$
$$
=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)^n} +2n(I_n - I_{n+1)}
$$
maybe you can take it from there?

Comment: Yes, thank you so much! :)

Comment: my pleasure! the interesting thing about this question is that it leads off in three slightly different directions. the first is the pragmatic one - evaluate $I_{n+1}$ by progressing back to the case n=1 which integrates (by substitution $x=tan \theta)$ as the $tan^{-1}$ (arctan) function. or, secondly, go the other way and get an intriguing series expansion for $tan^{-1}$. or thirdly, make the trig substitution directly into $I_n$ which leads the the interesting case of $\int cos^{2n} \theta $. for me it is these remarkable hidden connections which make math endlessly fascinating ;-)